# Trigger Shake Event in iOS SDK programatically

Tags: ios, ios4

Is it possible to trigger the shake programatically? I am using the undo manager in my iOS app and its working fine when I shake the device. In addition, I would like to be able to provide a UIButton, so a user can trigger the undo manager without actually shaking the device.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just call the `-undo` method on an instance of `NSUndoManager`, so set your button up to trigger that.

In addition, [this tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-1-shake-to-undoredo-nsundomanager/) may be helpful. It sets up an undo button as well as allowing shake to undo.

Comment: Hi Peng, Calling the undo/redo methods will perform the appropriate operations. To achieve this, I need to insert two buttons one for undo and another for redo. My initial question was how to trigger the shake event, so I can see the standard Undo/Redo Alert View shown the iOS. Hope I didn't confuse you too much.

Comment: @user320587: Not sure on that one. I was responding to "so a user can trigger the undo manager without actually shaking the device".